# Get start and end row number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet that contains the following data:

```
  A   |B  
--------
1|DOG |1
2|CAT |1
3|CAT |2
4|CAT |3
5|FROG|1
```

where column A contains animal kinds and B contains some other data. I need a formula that will tell me which row number a particular animal kind starts and ends at. So for instance if I was looking for CAT I could get the starting row number as 2 and ending row number of 4.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I don't see my fine answer in the question that this duplicates. I'm voting to re-open.

Comment: @DougGlancy, your answer may very well be fine, but the duplicate closure is about a duplicate of the question, not the answer. Maybe you should copy your answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie, you are right of course, and your idea is a good one.

Comment: @DougGlancy As fine as your answer may be, it's not actually an answer to the question asked, because the Q asks for a _formula_ (backed up by the OPs choice to acept the other answer). Aside from that the point of dup-close is to consolidate the information into one place, with search breadcrumb trails to help future searchers get _their_ answers. Simon's advise to duplicating answers doesn't help. Perhaps these two Q's could be merged (not sure how that process works) [seems like a flag is required](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262499/445425) (your thoughts?)

Comment: @chrisneilsen, thanks, I'm fine with things as they stand. I was being a bit silly about the fineness of my answer. I will say that sometimes good answers propose a different type of solution than the questioner envisioned. I'm sure if I looked I could find examples in your fine body of work.

Comment: @DougGlancy I'm actually more interested in your take on Merging closed-as-dup Q's.  I can see two contrary arguments. 1) merging removes part of the trail, making it more difficult for future users to find good info. 2) consolidating good answers (both good on-Q answers, and good alternative thinking answers, of which yours is an example) creates a richer pool of knowledge for when future user _do_ find the Q. Of course, when you have a good new answer to a dup Q, it's best VTC as dup, _and_ add the answer to the pointed-to dup. But given that that so often doesn't happen, the merge Q arrises

Comment: @chrisneilsen, given the rule of thumb stated at the end of your linked question, I'd say these two are good candidates for merging. The answer to the original is a bit better as it doesn't require sorting, but the accepted answer here has the benefit of not being array-entered. I'd say give it a try and see what happens. If it doesn't work, I'll delete my answer here and copy to the original (I think that's what you're suggesting). Regarding the more general issues you raise, I'd say that, with any effort, people are very likely to find one of these answers either way.

Comment: @Doug done - we'll see what happens...

Comment: @Doug merge declined with reason _merge wouldn't work, because the data sets are different_ Hmmm...

Comment: @chrisneilsen, that's a pretty high bar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following set up:

[image]

Put this formula in E2:

```
=MATCH(D2,A$1:A$4,0)
```

and this in F2:

```
=E2+COUNTIF(A$1:A$4,D2)-1
```

and drag down as needed.

Comment: This assumes the list is sorted. Keep in mind

Comment: @Steve not _sorted_ as such, but _grouped_, ia all `Cat`'s together

Answer (score 0):

You will get some good formula answers I'm sure, but also consider a pivot table:

[image]

The row column is populated with the formula `=ROW()`.
The pivot table has two value fields; one set to the Min of Row the other to the Max.

It's dynamic and will account for whatever animals you add, especially if your list is in a structured table.